# php giving out blank pages (may be website setup)

Tags: php, html, css

Hi all I don't know if anyone will or can help me but for the last week or so I have been trying to make up a profile page setup on my website but I can not get the pages to register any echo's or jest even php (It gives me blank pages and or tell me an error 500 server error)

I have set up my website with a static page for my logo, navbar and footer and using a include line to get the content on the pages. (I hope that makes sense).

if I put any form of php into the content pages it give me errors of 500 server error and or the pages just turns completely white.

Is there a specific way to show SQL content and or any PHP with this set up? if anyone knows any tutorials or could lend a hand that would be amazing (Any help will be placed onto the website on the Credits page).

Here is the static page code:

```
    <?php require '../connection/conn.php'; ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/Master.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/Menu.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/AboutImages.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/Form.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
        <div id="logindata"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <nav>
               <ul class="cssmenu">
                  <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="About.php">About Us</a></li>
                  <li><a href="Videos.php">Videos</a></li>
                  <li><a href="Contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                  <li><a href="Forum.php">Forum</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                  <li><a href="Account.php">My Account</a></li>
                  <li><a href="../connection/logoutscript.php">Logout</a></li>

                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
        <?php echo $content;?>

        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>All Rights Reserved, LPGamers.com, Created And Built by Robert Prince &amp; Amber Milton-White</p> <a href="#">Credits Page</a>
        </div>
 </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the content page:

```
    <?php

$title = 'LPGamers -- Personal Account';

$content = '
<div id="formbox">
    <form action="" method="GET">
        <p>Search for you friends here !</p>
        <input type="text" class="tfield">
        <input type="submit" class="button">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="ppicture">
    <img src="" />
</div>
<div class="pd">
    </br>
    <p class="pdp">
    Account id: # $userid
    </p>
    </br>
    <p class="pdp">
    Name: 
    </p>
    </br>
    <p class="pdp">
    Age: 
    </p>
    </br>
    <p class="pdp">
    Your Email: 
    </p>
    </br>
    <p class="pdp">
    Your Bio: 
    </p>
</div>
';

include ("Site_View.php");

?>
```

If this help any more Thanks in advance

Comment: can you put some sample code ? as this is very vague question and difficult to answer....

Comment: Turn on error reporting. Include the following code in the beginning of your scripts: `error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT); ini_set('display_errors', true);`

Answer (score 0):

Edited the answer, it looks like some content of the original post was not displayed initially.

1. Do not put the form in the PHP code, it is not needed. You want to put the result probably there.
2. If you want to get data from SQL in PHP do the following:
   Prerequisite: setup the php.ini to use whatever database you need, like:
   extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll

Define a database connection

```
$serverName = "myserver";
$usr="mySQLuser";
$pwd="mySQLpass";
$db="mydatabase";
$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $usr, "PWD" => $pwd, "Database" => $db);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( !$conn ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Use the SQL connection to retrieve data.

```
$sql = "Select name from Users where users.name = " . $myparam;
```

note: the example above is vulnerable to SQL injection, but it is an easy start for coding, you can fix this later when you are familiar with it. Also you need to give a value to $myparam first.

Then:

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
sqlsrv_next_result($stmt);
sqlsrv_fetch($stmt);
if( $stmt === false) {
  die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
```

Now you can use the data when you want, like this:

```
<?php
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
  $returnedName = $row['name'];
  echo $returnedName;
}
?>
```

Comment: i know this is going to sound stupid but im lost, i am extreamly new to php and it confuses me a little.

Comment: No problem, just say what you don't understand. This is the code that gets you the data from the SQL server, you can write it as a separate module and use an include to keep things cleaner, but you do need to: 1) define SQL connection; 2) define and run the SQL statement and 3) write in your  page the desired result.

Comment: i have tried this code but keep getting sqlsrv_connect() error on line 8 !

Comment: Can you post the code here, just remove username and password? Cannot guess what is on line 8 in your code.